PDU power input
I am trying to figure out if a PDU AP8853 that is build for LAM, EMEA, GCN, APJ can be installed in US and I am not sure if possible or not without any modifications to it. It comes with IEC-309 32A plug which is 3 prong plug. According to the plug manufacturer the plug in US can have 2 hots and a ground, and in EU hot, neutral and a ground and here is the link to plug IEC-309 32A plug
Also the PDU internally schematic diagram is this 
Now, in the US getting 240V you have to have 2 hots, each carrying 120V. Is this particular model AP8853 compatible with 240 voltage in US? I was told that it can be because When there are dual hots, the 2nd hot would be the neutral for the 1st and the 1st would be the neutral for the 2nd, to complete the circuit. Is that possible true in this scenario?
=========== Clarifying edit ================
This is a technical question about electrical circuiting and voltage not about modding a device customize it nor insurance policy or any other stuff.
It is a question if this device will work as was build intended for the voltage.
Thanks to @Triplefault for posting the link to the product datasheet
which I suppose to do myself in the first place.
The unit comes with its own plug which is IEC-309 32 A that can be easily paired with a proper receptacle like this

Now the plug/receptacle manufacturer has a cordage info that shows EU and US wiring diagram here

So back to the technical question, can this unit AP8853 be plugged into an outlet/receptacle that provides 240V on 2 pins(2 hots + ground) according to its electrical diagram?
Please refrain yourself from biased comments to insurance, liability, NEC or some others. It is a technical question and answers needs to be supported.
Thanks all for understanding.
This is not a question about product recommendation, and appreciate if a moderator can reopen it.

@crip659, BTW this PDU(power distribution unit) device is rated to work 50/60Hz, but your comment is a little off topic.

I see no circuit breaker on the "neutral"/2nd-hot. This means the second hot is not over-current protected and if a CB trips, one side of the outlets is still hot. Not a good idea,

Is this a home improvement or a data center question?

@AloysiusDefenestrate Could be a commercial data center. Could be somebody mining at home.

@AloysiusDefenestrate it is a data center question

@cadobe Real data centers (as opposed to "kind of like a data center, but at home") are off-topic here. Why? Because in most places (at least in the US) commercial electrical work requires a license and can't normally be DIY.

@manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact I state that "scenario" I wasn't say that I need nor I have to install into a DC or as you called "home DC". It is a discussion theory based on my previous debate with some fellas called themselves electricians and/or contractors. So the bottom line is just a simple question based on a provided dwg, not a question how to do it, nor asking for sizing. But appreciate your input.

RE the edit: NEC is the big moose on campus in the USA. If you ignore NEC, you're done. The Law will get you eventually. Insurance is a smaller but still big moose. You won't get paid when the fire starts. It is not wise to ignore these things. Per the answer from @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact the 240V electricity will run in this unit but only be half protected. Please refrain yourself from using this device in the USA. Get a USA-legal unit.

The product datasheet for the PDU AP8853 does not mention UL or ETL standards listings. It does mention European Union regulations. I lean towards possible insurance problems using this unit in the US, even in a house, even if the cable ends can be modified.

I see no inherent issue with running this type of equipment, with the right plugs, in the US. But the details do matter.

Circuit Size

This entire contraption is rated at 32A. If that does not include an NEC-mandated continuous use derate then you need a 40A circuit and appropriate wire. If 32A already includes a derate then you need any size circuit and breaker 32A or up - which means you end up with a 35A breaker. I'm not sure what cord/plug you can actually use with a 35A circuit. With a 40A circuit you use either a 6-50 (no neutral, only 240V) or a 14-50 (with neutral, 120V/240V but you don't actually use the neutral with this PDU in a US installation.)

Internal Breakers

The internal breakers, which I suspect are 16A as that is a common European size, but could be 20A, only break one hot line and not neutral. Since you are using a hot line as "neutral" that could be a safety issue.

240V Only

A lot of ordinary computer equipment sold for use in the US - desktop and laptop computers, monitors, etc. - can work automatically with 120V or 240V. However, some equipment may work only with 120V. This PDU only provides one voltage (240V nominal in the US) and would not provide any 120V receptacles. In addition, since the receptacles on the PDU are C13 and C19, it will work well for most computers and monitors but a lot of other equipment, even if it will work on both 120V and 240V, will not include a "C" type connector and instead use either a hard-wired plug/cord with a NEMA 5-15 plug, a proprietary connector or a USB connection with a provided "wall wart" with a NEMA 5-15 plug.
There are workarounds for all of these issues, but you may be better off with something designed for the US market.

I am not an electrician but AFAIK in US probably rarely find a 240V appliance that has and use neutral. And where is the point to "14-50 (with neutral, 120V/240V but you don't actually use the neutral with this PDU in a US installation.)" The AP8853, let's call it appliance is meant for 240V and has a built in plug

"rarely"? Not at all rare. Typical is: cooktop (no oven), water heater, EVSE = 240V; clothes dryer, oven, range (cooktop + oven) = 120V/240V. So in fact the typical house will be wired up with at least 2 120V/240V circuits, with the dryer almost always a receptacle and the oven sometimes a receptacle, sometimes (my preference) hardwired.

my dryer is gas and is running on 120V :)

FYI, that is why a typical electric dryer is 120V/240V - the manufacturer will use the same: control panel, timer, motor, light, buzzer, etc. for gas and electric. All of that is done in 120V. The only difference is: ignitor + gas valve + burner vs. 240V heating element.

Modifying the plug of an AP8853 is a violation of NEC 110.3(B).  The manufacturer specifically states, "No user-serviceable parts", and the unit requires a dedicated circuit with a single-pole circuit breaker.
If this was a switched PDU (model # shows it is metered, not switched) then you could entirely defeat the purpose of the PDU on a USA 240 VAC system with single pole switching.  Potentially lethal if any of those loads are ungrounded.
To offer some anecdotal background, I once disassembled a PDU of the same brand that had been damaged and was going to the trash.  I observed entire extra busses, ammeters, and the like, that were not connected to anything, but part of the design of similar model numbers.  It's cheaper for them to make common parts and put them in slightly different electrical configurations.  That does not mean it would be safe or legal to swap cords.
